# Extended DISTINCT SELECT

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
Date........................... Value
2013-09-24................ 10
2013-09-24................ 11
2013-09-24................ 12
2013-09-25................ 10
2013-09-25................ 13
```

What I want is to have the `DISTINCT SELECT` which returns dates without duplicates BUT with values summarized per date. So the result I want is:

```
2013-09-24................ 33
2013-09-25................ 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the aggregate function `sum()` with a `GROUP BY` to get the result:

```
select date, sum(value) Total
from yourtable
group by date;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b71e/1).

The `sum()` function adds the items in the `value` column, for each column that you are grouping by...`date`

Answer (score 1):

use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Date, SUM(Value) TotalValue
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8ff0/1)

This assumes that your time for dates are the same.